# Installing JSHint on VS Code

Tags: jshint

I tried to install JSHint through command, but I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\user>npm install -g jshint 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Your problem is not jshint, it's the fact that you don't have `npm` installed. Look for `npm` installation instructions for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed node try the below. Otherwise first install node.

Open the Control Panel (Click the Start button, then click Control Panel)

Click User Accounts

Click Change my environment variables

Select PATH and click the Edit... button

At the end of the Variable value, add ;C:\Program Files\nodejs

Click Ok on the "Edit User Variable" window, then click Ok on the "Environment Variables" window

Start a command prompt window (Start button, then type cmd into the search and hit enter)

At the prompt (C:>) type npm and hit enter; you should now see some help text (Usage: npm  etc.) rather than "npm is not recognized..."